# Reverse for 'guestbook.posts' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, django

I keep getting this error and I've spent hours trying to figure out what is wrong with my code.

Here are my files:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.utils import timezone

from guestbook.models import Post

# Create your views here.
def posts(request):
    if (request.POST.get('name', 0)):
        name = request.POST['name']
        text = request.POST['text']
        title = request.POST['titile']
        p = Post(name=name, title=title, text=text, pub_date=timezone.now())
        p.save()
    newest = Post.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('guestbook/index.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'newest_post': newest,
        'kalli': 543
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))

def write(request):
    return render(request, 'guestbook/form.html')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include

from guestbook import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.posts, name='posts'),
        url(r'^write', views.write, name='writer'),
)
```

*/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^guestbook/', include('guestbook.urls', namespace="guestbook")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

My error is somewhere in this file, But I put in other codes in the question just in case,

> NoReverseMatch at /guestbook/write
>
> Reverse for 'guestbook.posts' with arguments '()' and keyword
>   arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
>
> Request Method:   GET Request URL:
>     localhost:8000/guestbook/write Django Version:  1.6.6
>   Exception Type:   NoReverseMatch Exception Value:
>
> Reverse for 'guestbook.posts' with arguments '()' and keyword
>   arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
>
> Exception Location:
>     c:\python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py in
>   _reverse_with_prefix, line 456 Python Executable:     c:\python33\python.exe Python Version:  3.3.5

The above is my Error.

forum.html

```
What's you name?<br>
<form action="{% url 'guestbook.posts' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="title">
    <textarea rows=15 cols=100 name="text">
    <input type="submit" value="Send post">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reverse namespaced URLs, you'll need to refer to them as `guestbook:posts` rather than `guestbook.posts`, per [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls).

Comment: This trick helped me. But I'm confused as I have code that works e.g. like this:
`<a href="{% url 'some-index' %}">Some</a>`
but second url works only with app name
`<a href="{% url 'app_name:some2-index' %}">Some2</a>`
What could be the issue here? `some-index` is e.g. from app_nr1, and `some2-index` is from app_nr2. But they work differently event they are used e,g, in the same html template? How can I find the cause of this?